# Incrementing values in a JavaScript object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

A particular problem asked to return the first unique value (i.e. a value that appears only once in an array). My approach was to create an obj with keys as elements in the array and the values as a counter for how many times each value was seen.

```
function solution(arr) {
  let uniqueObj = {}
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(uniqueObj[arr[i]] !== undefined){
      uniqueObj[arr[i]] = uniqueObj[arr[i]] + 1
    }
    uniqueObj[arr[i]] = 1
  }
  console.log(uniqueObj) 
}
solution([4,10,5,4,2,10])

//output { '2': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1, '10': 1 }
```

why isn't the value incrementing each time the same key is seen?

Comment: You are resetting it to 1 with uniqueObj[arr[i]] = 1

Comment: That line should be in an `else` block.

Comment: BTW, you can use `++` to increment a value, so you don't have to write the whole expression twice.

Answer (score 1):

After your if statement you're resetting `uniqueObj[arr[i]]` back to 1. You need add an else clause for when `uniqueObj` doesn't have the value at `arr[i]`:

```
if (uniqueObj[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
    uniqueObj[arr[i]] += 1;
} else { // add else block
    uniqueObj[arr[i]] = 1      
}
```